# Add div after every three items in a loop?

Tags: wordpress, loops

I am working with a WP website and in my template I am running the loop like this:

```
<!-- START LOOP -->
                <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

                    <div class="row" style="margin:15px 0;">
                        <div class="twelve columns">
                            <div class="four columns">
                                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                                    <?php 
                                        if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
                                            the_post_thumbnail( 'medium' );
                                        } else {
                                            echo 'No Preview Available'; 
                                        } 
                                    ?>
                                </a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="eight columns">

                                <h3><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title() ?></a></h3>
                                <p><?php the_excerpt() ?></p>
                                <p><a href="<?php echo esc_html( get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'portfolio_website', true ) ); ?>" target="_blank"><?php echo esc_html( get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'portfolio_website', true ) ); ?></a></p>

                            </div>  

                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <hr />

                <?php endwhile; ?>
```

Because this is a responsive website, I am trying to get a grid column look.  The problem I am having is how I can insert a div with a class or "row container" after every third item?

I know I probably just confused the crap out of you because I confuse myself but in short the html would look like this:

```
<div class="row container">
    <!-- item 1 -->
    <div class="twelve columns">
        <div class="four columns">IMAGE HERE</div>
        <div class="eight columns">TEXT HERE</div>
    </div>

    <!-- item 2 -->
    <div class="twelve columns">
        <div class="four columns">IMAGE HERE</div>
        <div class="eight columns">TEXT HERE</div>
    </div>

    <!-- item 3 -->
    <div class="twelve columns">
        <div class="four columns">IMAGE HERE</div>
        <div class="eight columns">TEXT HERE</div>
    </div>

    <!-- item 4 -->
    <div class="twelve columns">
        <div class="four columns">IMAGE HERE</div>
        <div class="eight columns">TEXT HERE</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and so on, instead I would like it to display in a grid so the HTML should look more like this:

```
<div class="row container">
    <!-- row 1 -->
    <div class="twelve columns">
        <div class="four columns">
            <!-- item 1 -->
            <div class="four columns">IMAGE HERE</div>

            <!-- item 2 -->
            <div class="four columns">IMAGE HERE</div>

            <!-- item 3 -->
            <div class="four columns">IMAGE HERE</div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- row 2 -->
    <div class="twelve columns">
        <div class="four columns">
            <!-- item 4 -->
            <div class="four columns">IMAGE HERE</div>

            <!-- item 5 -->
            <div class="four columns">IMAGE HERE</div>

            <!-- item 6 -->
            <div class="four columns">IMAGE HERE</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I can do everything else Im just not sure how to implement the below so I get the results I pasted above?  I have found this online and feel like it is a step in the right direction:

```
<?php ($i % 3) == 0 ?>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your feelings are right.

You can use the `$current_post` property of the [`WP_Query` class](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/WP_Query) to get the index of the post currently displayed in the loop, and then use the [modulus operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php) to make sure you are targeting multiples of three.

So your loop could look like this:

```
 <div class="row container">
      <!-- row -->
      <div class="twelve columns">
           <div class="four columns">
      <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

                <!-- item -->            
                <div class="four columns">IMAGE HERE</div>

      <?php if( $wp_query->current_post % 3 == 0 ) : ?>
           </div>
      </div>
      <!-- row -->
      <div class="twelve columns">
           <div class="four columns">
      <?php endif; ?>        
      <?php endwhile; ?>
</div>
```

You might need to improve this implementation. Specifically, make sure that, whatever happens, your HTML closes correctly.

Comment: Lol thanks, I just found it as I believe you were writing that but your version looks much cleaner ;)

Comment: Yes, your version should work fine. Advantages of mine is that you don't need an extra-counter, because Wordpress already keeps track of it using the `$current_post` propriety. And also, overrall it's cleaner to use the `if blocks` so that you can transition between HTML and PHP more smoothly than using the `echo` statements. All in all, no big deals performance-wise.

Answer (score 1):

What I needed was a counter:

```
<!-- START LOOP -->
            <?php $counter = 1 ?>
            <div class="row" style="margin:15px 0;">
                    <div class="twelve columns">
            <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>


                        <div class="four columns">
                            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                                <?php 
                                    if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
                                        the_post_thumbnail( 'medium' );
                                    } else {
                                        echo 'No Preview Available'; 
                                    } 
                                ?>
                            </a>
                        </div>  
                        <?php if ($counter % 3 == 0){echo '</div></div></hr /><div class="row" style="margin:15px 0;"><div class="twelve columns">';} ?>                            


            <?php $counter++ ; 
            endwhile; ?>
            </div>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
 
$currentPage = get_query_var('paged');
 
 
// General arguments
 
$posts = new WP_Query(array(
    'post_type' => 'post', // Default or custom post type
    'posts_per_page' => 11, // Max number of posts per page
    'paged' => $currentPage
));
 


// Content display
$i = 0;            
if ($posts->have_posts()) :
    while ($posts->have_posts()) :
        $posts->the_post();
        if( $i % 3 == 0 )      
            echo '<section class="columns">';
               
        echo "<div class='column'>";
               ?>
             
                    <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
                    <p><?php the_excerpt(); ?></p>
            
               <?php        
        
        echo "</div>";  
               $i++;
             
             if( $i % 3 == 0 )     
            echo '</section>';
             
    endwhile;
endif;
 
?>
               
        
            
             
            <?php
             
// Bottom pagination (pagination arguments)
 
echo "<div class='page-nav-container'>" . paginate_links(array(
    'total' => $posts->max_num_pages,
    'prev_text' => __('<'),
    'next_text' => __('>')
)) . "</div>";
             
             ?>
```