# Appending wrapper div conditionally using index value in ice:panelSeries

Tags: jsf, icefaces

I have this UI structure:

```
<ice:panelSeries value="#{bean.list}" var="item" varStatus="vs">
    <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="span6"></div>
    </div>
</ice:panelSeries>
```

I want to create `div.row-fluid` using modules condition `#{vs.index % 2 == 0}`, so that `div.row-fluid` is appended after two `span6` divs, to create a dynamic grid-view.

I have tried inner content wrapped with `ice:panelGroup` using `rendered="#{vs.index % 2 == 0}"` but this hides the row when condition becomes true.

Also, I have tried wrapping `div.row-fluid` with `c:if` tag, as we normally do to create html element dynamically in some other languages:

```
<c:if test="#{vs.index % 2 == 0}"><div class="row-fluid"><c:if>
    <div class="span4"></div>
<c:if test="#{vs.index % 2 == 0}"></div><c:if>
```

This causes page to crash saying `<div>` is not properly closed. 
The main problem is that I have to place separate opening and closing div.

**Is there any way to achieve this in JSF using icefaces components???**

Comment: Related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17871513/add-div-after-every-three-items-in-a-loop

Comment: Why not just repeat the whole block and give them different rendered values (negated)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *This causes page to crash saying `<div>` is not properly closed*

You can trick this with passing escaped XML through `<h:outputText escape="false">`.

```
<h:outputText value="&lt;div class=&quot;row-fluid&quot;&gt;" escape="false" rendered="#{vs.index mod 2 eq 0}" />
    <div class="span4"></div>
<h:outputText value="&lt;/div&gt;" escape="false" rendered="#{vs.index mod 2 eq 0}" />
```

Comment: It didn't work either. Now .row-fluid divs are appearing as plain text not as the container div elements.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot the `escape="false"` in the snippet and you apparently copypasted it without actually reading/understanding the answer :) I fixed the snippet.

Comment: I did copy-paste, even I read comment above it to include escape="false" :P And tried with it before your edit. Anyways, its working. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You have two options, depending on your real achievement:

1. If you want to control statically (on the server side) how content must be displayed, then simply put your beans in an 2D array instead of a list, and then use two nested loops in the UI declaration
2. If rows don't have any business meaning, but are solely intended as a mean to best use the horizontal monitor space, then use some grid framework to work exclusively on the client side, possibly in a responsive manner. For example with Twitter Bootstrap one [can write](http://www.bootply.com/vzwxMXeqer):

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6 O"></div>
      <div class="col-md-6 O"></div>
      <div class="col-md-6 O"></div>
      <div class="col-md-6 O"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

without creating multiple rows in the markup